# The number of real roots of $2x^5+8x-7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a (theoretical) method to tell the number of real roots of $$2x^5+8x-7=0?$$

Note, without using calculator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polynomial is increasing. It is negative at $x=0$ and positive at $x=1$, thus it has exactly one real root, and it's somewhere between those two points.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Descartes' Sign Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DescartesSignRule.html),

if $f(x)=2x^5+8x-7$

Since there is only one sign change, there is a maximum of one possible positive root,so has exactly one positive root as the degree of $f(x)$ is $3$ with real coefficients,so complex roots will occur in pair.

For $f(-x)=-2x^5-8x-7$

Since there is no sign change, there is no possible negative root for $f(x)$.

So, the number of real roots is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a pretty standard MVT+ Rolle Theorem problem...

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=2x^5+8x-7$. Then $f'(x)=10x^4+8$. How many roots does $f'$ have? Ho many roots could then have $f$?

Can you use the IVT to finish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can take the derivative:

$f(x) = 2x^5 + 8x - 7 \Rightarrow f'(x) = 10x^4 + 8$

As even powers are always positive, the derivative is always positive as well. If $f'(x)$ is always positive, $f(x)$ can only cross the x-axis once and there's only one real root.